# How to transfer Jenkins FreeStyle and Multibranch pipelines to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm a beginner to Azure DevOps. I need suggestions on how to make Jenkins Total Jobs (.Net Jobs On-premises) like Azure DevOps Jobs. Currently, we are using Windows agent servers for our Jenkins jobs and we need to configure the same servers as Azure DevOps agent servers. Could you please provide sample YAML and Jenkinsfile scripts to help us with this? Thank you.
Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Expecting:

1. Jenkins Jobs with the same configurations and build/test jobs results need to be met.
2. Windows agent servers need to transfer as Azure DevOps agent Servers
3. The agent servers should be the same configurations after making those as Azure DevOps agent nodes
4. Upstream and Downstream jobs
5. Freestyle, Multibranch pipeline jobs in Azure DevOps
6. How to use Multiple jobs using the same Repo
7. How to give user permissions to single org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To migrate from Jenkins to Azure Pipelines, you can see this doc [Migrate from Jenkins to Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/migrate/from-jenkins?view=azure-devops) for the detailed info. This document provides a guide to translate a Jenkins pipeline configuration to Azure Pipelines, information about moving container-based builds and selecting build agents, mapping environment variables, and how to handle success and failures of the build pipeline.

Azure DevOps pipeline can run on [Microsoft-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#microsoft-hosted-agents) and [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#install). Based on your description, it seems that you want to run the pipeline on your local machine. You can follow the doc to [set up a Self-hosted Windows agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops).

In DevOps pipeline, you can use [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages) to configure dependency between jobs/stages. You can also use [pipeline trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops) to run a pipeline automatically. Azure Pipelines supports many types of triggers. For example, the completion of "pipelineA" can trigger "pipelineB".

Azure Repos includes free unlimited private Git repos, you can [create multiple branches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-branch?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) in one repo and create pipelines based on any branch you want.

It is recommended that you first check the [documentation related to the DevOps pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/?view=azure-devops) to have some basic understanding of the DevOps pipeline, and then ask specific questions about specific issues.

About managing permission in the org, you can see [Get started with permissions and access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) for the detailed info.